# what value was present at each 2.5s interval (resampling?) numpy

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation

I have a numpy array with a value in the first column, and time in seconds in the second column. Using the timing info in the second column, I need to end up with a vector of the col 1 value at each 2.5s interval. The 2nd column contains onset times, and each trial is 9s long. So the first trial lasts from 0.01s-9.01s. The time values don't perfectly line up with 2.5s intervals, so I want to use the col 1 value only if it's present for more than half of the 2.5s interval. I need to end up with 172 values, from 0 to 430 seconds.

```
array([[0.00, 0.01],
   [1.91, 9.60],
   [0.00, 19.08],
   [2.05, 28.64],
   [1.04, 38.19],
   [1.89, 47.73],
   [1.69, 57.27],
   [2.24, 66.79],
   [1.89, 76.33],
   [1.86, 85.88],
   [2.37, 95.39],
   [2.29, 104.93],
   [2.03, 114.45],
   [2.16, 123.99],
   [1.34, 133.52],
   [2.40, 143.03],
   [2.17, 152.54],
   [0.00, 162.03],
   [1.61, 171.59],
   [2.31, 181.13],
   [2.15, 190.67],
   [2.22, 200.19],
   [2.16, 209.72],
   [0.00, 219.20],
   [2.65, 228.76],
   [1.74, 238.33],
   [0.00, 247.85],
   [2.33, 257.42],
   [1.85, 266.94],
   [0.00, 276.50],
   [2.27, 286.06],
   [1.67, 295.62],
   [2.41, 305.15],
   [0.00, 314.65],
   [1.32, 324.21],
   [2.39, 333.74],
   [2.19, 343.27],
   [2.51, 352.81],
   [2.41, 362.33],
   [1.79, 371.86],
   [0.00, 381.36],
   [3.07, 390.93],
   [2.30, 400.47],
   [0.00, 409.98],
   [2.41, 419.54],
   [2.22, 0.05],
   [1.75, 9.59],
   [2.18, 19.14],
   [1.99, 28.64],
   [1.80, 38.16],
   [1.45, 47.68],
   [1.57, 57.21],
   [2.24, 66.74],
   [0.00, 76.24],
   [2.31, 85.80],
   [0.00, 95.29],
   [2.39, 104.85],
   [0.00, 114.34],
   [0.95, 123.89],
   [2.35, 133.42],
   [2.43, 142.98],
   [1.66, 152.48],
   [1.08, 162.01],
   [0.00, 171.53],
   [1.20, 181.08],
   [2.43, 190.64],
   [2.42, 200.16],
   [2.59, 209.69],
   [1.98, 219.22],
   [1.75, 228.76],
   [2.28, 238.28],
   [1.98, 247.80],
   [1.08, 257.33],
   [2.08, 266.84],
   [2.30, 276.37],
   [0.00, 285.84],
   [1.38, 295.40],
   [2.19, 304.95],
   [0.00, 314.44],
   [1.54, 324.01],
   [2.19, 333.52],
   [0.00, 343.02],
   [2.13, 352.59],
   [2.31, 362.13],
   [0.00, 371.61],
   [2.36, 381.18],
   [2.02, 390.71],
   [2.68, 400.24],
   [0.00, 409.71],
   [2.19, 419.28]])
```

I previously tried interpolating using interp1d but that smooths the data a bit and I really want to use the original values. I just need some guidance on how I might do that because it seems really complicated. Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "present for more than half of the 2.5 second interval"? How can a value be present for a certain amount of time when it looks like your sampling rate is roughly every ten seconds?

Comment: Sorry, I've edited to be clearer. The times are trial onset times, and each trial lasts 9 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Your data contain 2 consecutive datasets, which don't agree with one another and appear both to be heavily undersampled (huge jumps, very little continuity). Since the time between samples is 9.5 secs on average, I don't think that any kind of resampling at 2.5 sec intervals is going to give any real value. Unless you have a whole lot of phase changes or are sampling something with a built-in modulo operation like a Fresnel lens, I don't think your data are sampled often enough.

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as p
%matplotlib inline

data=np.array([[0.00, 0.01],
   [1.91, 9.60],
   ...      
   [0.00, 409.71],
   [2.19, 419.28]])

data=data.transpose()
p.figure(figsize=(12,6))
p.subplot(121)
print len(data[0])
dat1=data[:,:45]
dat2=data[:, 45:]
p.plot(dat1[1],dat1[0],'.-')
p.plot(dat2[1],dat2[0]+3,'.-')
p.title ('actual data (half offset for clarity)')

# plot the time steps
p.subplot(122)
p.plot(np.diff(dat1[1]))
p.plot(np.diff(dat2[1]))
p.title('time differences between samples ~ 9.5 secs')
```

[image]